# How to properly map a function to every record of a dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

### Goal

I'm trying to prepare my dataset for image segmentation. I converted all images and their associated annotations into `.tfrecord` files using the following code:

```
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecords_filename)

for img_path, annotation_path in filename_pairs:
    img = np.array(Image.open(img_path))
    annotation = np.array(Image.open(annotation_path))
    height = img.shape[0]
    width = img.shape[1]

    img_raw = img.tostring()
    annotation_raw = annotation.tostring()

    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'height': _int64_feature(height),
        'width': _int64_feature(width),
        'image_raw': _bytes_feature(img_raw),
        'mask_raw': _bytes_feature(annotation_raw)}))

    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

Now, I'm trying to load these records into a TF dataset:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(training_filenames).shuffle(1000).repeat(4).batch(32)
```

### Experiment

Now if I try to display the first image/annotation couple in this `dataset`, it works as expected if I do:

```
batch = next(iter(dataset))
tensor = batch[0]

image, annotation = _parse_function(tensor)
annotation = np.squeeze(annotation.numpy()[:, :], axis=2)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image.numpy())
plt.imshow(annotation, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

where I preprocess the record using `_parse_function` to extract the features back (**I'm purposefully using TensorFlow in eager execution mode**):

```
def _parse_function(example_proto):
    features = {'height': tf.FixedLenFeature(1, tf.int64),
                'width': tf.FixedLenFeature(1, tf.int64),
                'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                'mask_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)}
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)

    annotation = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['mask_raw'], tf.uint8)

    height = tf.cast(parsed_features['height'], tf.int32)
    width = tf.cast(parsed_features['width'], tf.int32)
    height = height.numpy()[0]
    width = width.numpy()[0]

    image = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)

    image = tf.reshape(image, tf.stack([height, width, 3]))
    annotation = tf.reshape(annotation, tf.stack([height, width, 1]))

    return image, annotation
```

### Actual problem

Of course I'd rather turn the entire `dataset` into something directly usable to train a segmentation model.

However, if I try to preprocess the entire `dataset` to turn it into a set of features, using `dataset.map(_parse_function)`, the `example_proto` that's being fed into `_parse_function` seems to be different than what I get when doing `next(iter(dataset))[0]`. More precisely, it's a tensor of rank 0 (so just a magnitude) and so the features can't be extracted properly.

I'm still relatively new to TF and don't quite understand why it's the case nor what this tensor represents.

Does `map` call the callback function on batches instead of the underlying examples? I tried removing the `batch(32)` but the documentation says the default behavior is to generate batches of size 1, which wouldn't necessarily solve the problem.

Any help would be appreciated!